# Sinon spy on WebSocket

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, websocket, sinon

I am trying to spy on WebSocket construction using sinon.js with this code ([requirebin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=12120d41a12bb90e7c62)):

```
sinon = require('sinon');

sinon.spy(window, 'WebSocket');
// throws an error (see console)
new window.WebSocket("ws://example.com");
```

In Chrome it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

In Safari or PhantomJs it fails with `TypeError: Attempted to wrap object property WebSocket as function`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from a sinon collaborator on github: https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/743

TL;DR: Native objects are unreliable as spying/stubbing targets. Wrap them into your own thin wrappers and then spy/stub those:

```
// totally making things up here
function WrapWebSocket(){
    return window.WebSocket;
}

// in your code
function init(){
    var WS = WrapWebSocket();
    var ws = new WS();
}

// in your test
var spy = sinon.spy();
sinon.stub(window, 'WrapWebSocket', function(){
    return spy;
});
init();
assert(spy.calledWith('someurl');
```